# Find what parameters should I send for a POST request

Tags: json, web-services, parameters, http-post

I am trying to call a web service with a POST request, but I do not know the name of parameters that should be sent in the request. All I know is the address of the web service. Based on that, how can I find the parameters names?

Thank you for your advice,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For SOAP services you could get the interface from published WSDL. For HTTP based web services (REST), [WADL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) was designed to describe the functionality, but it is not widely used, and it is not standarized by W3C.

Therefore, if you are not using SOAP, I suggest to look at documentation